# Keyerror when indexing using the iterrows() function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to simply load a dataframe and iterate through it with Pandas iterrows(). However, I get a KeyError when I try to access elements using the index that is given by the iterrows() function. Does anyone know why that happens?

```
def filter_felt(df):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if df["Felt"][i] == 1 or df["Felt"][i] == 2 or df["Felt"][i] == "Totalt":
            df = df.drop([i])
            print(df["Felt"][i])
    
    return df

filter_felt(data)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take a look at the post [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order to let us understand what's is causing your problem is always recommended to add the full error message as well as a sample of the data you're using.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that my problem was that I try to drop the row while iterating over the dataframe.